# Can not combine two CA certificate files to a CA certificate chain

Tags: firefox, security, certificate, https, openssl

Ι' m trying to concatenate two valid self-signed CA pem files generated using openssl in order to import a single CA file in Firefox (client side), using the following command:

**cat CA_file0.pem CA_file1.pem > CA_combination.pem**

Let CA_file1.pem corresponds to `https://my_first_url.com` (first Apache server) and CA_file2.pem corresponds to `https://my_second_url.com` (second Apache server) .

Unfortunately, when I import the CA_combination.pem in Firefox, the  second certificate (CA_file2.pem) is ignored and the connection to the second URL is presented as untrusted. Please, notice that:

a) I have installed the appropriate openssl files at the server side

b) when I import the ca_file*.pem files separately, Firefox establishes trusted connections.

**(new information)**

c) Printing the content of the concatenated file I see the following string which includes the '\n' character at the end of each line:

> '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIID3TCCAsWgAwIBAgIJANqUJ4kzYi5zMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGEMQswCQYD\nVQQGEwJHUjEPMA0GA1UECAwGR3JlZWNlMQ8wDQYDVQQHDAZQYXRyYXMxDzANBgNV\nBAoMBkNpdHJpeDETMBEGA1UECwwKQnl0ZW1vYmlsZTENMAsGA1UEAwwEQ1NSVjEe\nMBwGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYPY3NydkBjaXRyaXguY29tMB4XDTEzMDkxMTEyNTg1NloX\nDTE2MDcwMTEyNTg1NlowgYQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkdSMQ8wDQYDVQQIDAZHcmVlY2Ux\nDzANBgNVBAcMBlBhdHJhczEPMA0GA1UECgwGQ2l0cml4MRMwEQYDVQQLDApCeXRl\nbW9iaWxlMQ0wCwYDVQQDDARDU1JWMR4wHAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFg9jc3J2QGNpdHJp\neC5jb20wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQC/PAbpqGwp6mqo\nl4caHP+lfml5nfQZCVH5pGaPymrg2zLkl1/UoCZ0DGqad+51s3ejqH3HEh+fK0vc\n8J0+8GJx3NCIcqbgL4iFn/4RNFG7ogoV0swpNdcoySIyxUt0JUbtD7TkUDvYOOIt\nr4Sl/+1mzDgzvTONsMObAALSiajuLtj9YB2GL6CKTRgI+Oiw60htrSEj1MOWkjvY\nQkqwK9w36+QWZqxejoukqqOIWo8Nlphg22wWZgyM2RX5TQtr1yefUQdTnAVD0oh6\nIJBgv717S4SO6xKe6J5LsUKi6EAdJhl+188FlUcBifQz9C3iv7vpa2w2DGDUXVde\niKOX2wZ3AgMBAAGjUDBOMB0GA1UdDgQWBBRb1laXroXVRnmsXSDSJnd0v3VJujAf\nBgNVHSMEGDAWgBRb1laXroXVRnmsXSDSJnd0v3VJujAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0G\nCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQAR4IBqrBg9EMu5UXiF9a3NjZhVVeUhIh+C2JLhY9Mh\nc6iz6drdULRwIRiBxjE9W/BpD6dw4VT125RwQrSY/gaUkSMjdgMkFUJV7m0AjqUg\n6INLZS7AU6aBc7Wu0yl/HHTA+3JkJY2aFbmb8LZOIAef7XnWLZsAOcXwRMexb7XM\nyYMVd8WYFeO/EexubNkYGBK9y4Spg8jhX+M5SaHVnbQJ3/A4L9wdNzpuP4DItnJf\nBR7dds3CbeJi26lVLW94/mhzDpHkK2wVf7Z8WI3D67RBzaiRugxoT/Vx4pnPm/7y\n5N0NDWvopP8Zid08IkVAf7a6X7WcGaBo7MX64ctyBN/V\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nmILoj/vLo2rmeyNEELh90DX6pxl2MboQNWXKaP7NIMNJ\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n'

**(new information)**

d) By replacing every '\n' character by the '\r\n' characters the Firefox behavior remains the same using the concatenated CA file.

Is there an idea how to concatenate the CA pem files ?

**(new information)**

References:

[1] http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm

[2] http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/sametime/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.sametime.v8512.sut.doc%2Fosv_csr%2Fosv_csr_how_to_combine_certificate_files_to_certification_chain_task.html

Comment: Have you looked inside the files to see what the combined file looks like? By itself, `cat` will not add line-feeds at the end if they aren't there already, so it could merge lines. This page [1] has some guidelines. [1]: http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm

Comment: @beroe
Thank you for your response. Please, check the update of the initial post.

Comment: You are using Windows as the browser? When you say "remains the same" does that mean it does not work, or it works? Do you want to know how to `cat` the files and then replace `\n` with `\r\n`? Or you still need a way to join them and have the combined file work?

Comment: @beroe Thank you again fro the response! I use Mozilla Firefox as browser. When I say "remains the same" means that after the changes the system still does not work. I need a way to combine properly the certificates. I know how linux cat command works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I described at the initial post has been resolved. Finally, the issue I had was a misunderstanding during the completion of the openssl interactive terminal fields. To be more precise, the two different CAs had similar fields because of a bug in the script I wrote, so, by inserting a random sequence at each input field the issue solved.

Thank you guys for your help!